# Obtaining constant using the straight line gradient of two equations

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is the following:

We have two equations,

$$\left\langle R^2_j \right\rangle=\frac{1}{N_j}\sum\limits_1^{N_j}R^2_{i,j}$$

and

$$ \Delta^*_j=\frac{kT}{2D\sigma}[1-exp(-2\frac{\Delta_j}{\tau})]$$

Plotting $R^2_{i,j}$ against $[1-exp(-2\frac{\Delta_j}{\tau})]$, with different values of $\Delta_j$ (where $R^2_{i,j}$ is $\Delta_j$ dependent also), generates a straight line graph.

The constant I'm trying to find is $\sigma$. All other constants are known. According to my supervisor, we can obtain this constant by using the gradient of the plot, henceforth $p$. The solution that was given is:

$$\sigma=\frac{kT}{2Dp}$$

I assume it is also possible to have this as:

$$\sigma=\frac{kTp}{2D}$$

if the graph is plotted the other way. Could someone help explain how this is achieved? Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Could you insert the plot and some reference values? Thanks